# md-menu inside md-list-item as a second action button

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have got the code below in my project and I have got this problem. When I will add the `md-menu` component into my dynamically generated (`ng-repeat`) `md-list` component, it will show this error in JS console:

> Error: Invalid HTML for md-menu: Expected two children elements.

**My HTML code:**

```
<md-card>
    <md-card-content>
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">List</md-subheader>
            <md-list-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" ng-click="someAction()">
                <p>{{playlist[1]}}</p>
                <md-menu>
                    <md-icon aria-label="Action" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-secondary md-hue-3 material-icons">create</md-icon>
                    <md-menu-content>
                        <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="">Edit</md-button></md-menu-item>
                        <md-menu-item><md-button ng-click="">Remove</md-button></md-menu-item>
                    </md-menu-content>
                </md-menu>
            </md-list-item>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Can you help me to solve this issue please?

I think, that the problem is when the code is builded, it looks different and then `md-menu` component has got 2 child inside (2 button), but I don't know, how to resolve this.

**Here is the builded code:**

```
<md-list-item class="md-with-secondary ng-scope md-clickable" tabindex="-1" role="listitem" ng-repeat="playlist in playlists">
    <button tabindex="0" ng-click="someAction()" class="md-no-style md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="">
        <div class="md-list-item-inner ng-scope">
            <p class="ng-binding">test</p>
            <md-menu class="md-menu ng-scope">
                <md-menu-content>
                    <md-menu-item role="menuitem">
                        <button tabindex="0" type="button" ng-click="" class="md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="">
                            <span class="ng-scope">Edit</span>
                        </button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                    <md-menu-item role="menuitem">
                        <button tabindex="0" ng-click="" class="md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="">
                            <span class="ng-scope">Remove</span>
                        </button>
                    </md-menu-item>
                </md-menu-content>
            </md-menu>
        </div>
        <div style="" class="md-ripple-container"></div>
        <div style="" class="md-ripple-container"></div>
    </button>

    <button tabindex="0" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-secondary-container md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-transclude="">
        <md-icon tabindex="-1" aria-label="Open Chat" class="md-hue-3 material-icons ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">create</md-icon>
    </button>
</md-list-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also couldn't use md-menu inside md-list-item as a second action button when I was using Angular Material 1.0.0 RC1 but when I upgraded both js and css of Angular Material to 1.1.0 RC4 it worked. The working code is something like this and please notice the "md-secondary" class needs to be assigned to "md-menu":

```
<md-list flex>
    <md-subheader class="md-no-sticky">sub header</md-subheader>
    <md-list-item ng-click="goToPerson(person.name, $event)" class="md-2-line" ng-repeat="user in userManagement.users">
        <img alt="{{ 'person.name' }}" ng-src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2014/03/25/16/54/user-297566_960_720.png" class="md-avatar"/>
        <div class="md-list-item-text">
            <h3>{{ user.firstName }} {{ user.lastName }} </h3>
            <p>{{ user.email }} </p>
        </div>
        <md-menu md-position-mode="target-right target"  class="md-secondary">
            <md-button aria-label="Open demo menu" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
                <md-icon md-menu-origin>menu</md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-menu-content width="4">
                <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in [1, 2, 3]">
                    <md-button ng-click="ctrl.announceClick($index)">
                        <div layout="row" flex>
                            <p flex>Option {{item}}</p>
                            <md-icon md-menu-align-target md-svg-icon="call:portable-wifi-off" style="margin: auto 3px auto 0;"></md-icon>
                        </div>
                    </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
            </md-menu-content>
        </md-menu>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Every md-menu must specify exactly two child elements. The first
>   element is what is left in the DOM and is used to open the menu. This
>   element is called the trigger element.

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdMenu

I think your `ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)"` needs to be on a `md-button` element, not the `md-icon`

Comment: I tried to add the `md-button` directive, like:                             `<md-button ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)" class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Open sample menu">
                                <md-icon class="material-icons">create</md-icon>
                            </md-button>` but now, the `md-button` is don't have self click action (you can't click on this button) and when I will add a class `md-secondary` to this button, I will see the error, which I described in my question

Comment: heh ... thank you for your reply, I was tested this code in Firefox on Mac and it's not working correctly. Now I added the alert() function, which will fire, when you click on the list button. In Chrome, its allright (action fired only, when you click on the list button - but you can see the wrong clicked animation (its overlaying the whole element, not only right button)), but in Firefox is this action fired everytime, which you clicked on the row and the right menu will not show. New CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOpVgP

Answer (score -1):

go to source code of angular-material.js and add/modify that part... I will generate menu as secondary-item outside the item.

```
    // Check for a secondary item and move it outside
    if ( secondaryItem && (
    isMdMenu(secondaryItem) ||
    secondaryItem.hasAttribute('ng-click') ||
    ( tAttrs.ngClick &&
    isProxiedElement(secondaryItem) )
    )) {
       tEl.addClass('md-with-secondary');
       tEl.append(secondaryItem);
    }

    function isMdMenu(el) {
       var nodeName = el.nodeName.toUpperCase();

       return nodeName == "MD-MENU";
    }
```